# Laravel Vue Unknown custom component On production server

Tags: laravel, vuejs2

I am using Laravel as Backend and Vue Js as my frontend.
On the development, components works fine. I added new components later, when I push the changes to the production server I get [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element. I don't understand what I am missing because everything is well on development while on production is not. I ran npm run dev on production to compile the app.js file but still.

I have registered most of my components global using Vue.component.
image
app-accept-bill I added it after new changes were required, it fails on production

Comment: Have you tried `npm run prod`?

Comment: No, what does npm run prod do?

Comment: it builds your assets for a production environment.

Comment: Thanks, strange thing happened, I wrote a test route and check if I'd experience the same issue without running npm run prod, the component is showing without errors. Could this be some cached data on the browser or something?

Comment: Hi Adam, it works. Thanks.